Rust spots on stainless steel utensils after washed in the dishwasher
We've noticed recently (2-3 weeks) that stainless utensils are coming out of the dishwasher with rust spots. Could this be something with the dishwasher (we're thinking of getting a new one anyways), or could it be the dishwashing detergent? I've also notice some rust stains on the stainless interior of the dishwasher, but I thought it was just old stains. We're using Cascade Platinum gel packs.




Are you sure it's stainless steel?

Definitely. I added a couple more picture, including one of a knife with 'stainless' stamped.

Not an answer, but different utensils are different grades of SS. My wife bought a SS knife set from one of the brands considered sort of high end that clearly says it is not dishwasher safe. They get rust spots. We have SS cookware from the same brand that does not. We have SS cutlery that is less expensive that does not get the rust spots. I can't figure out why any manufacturer would make any SS kitchenware that is not dishwasher safe.

There are different grades of stainless steel,  Cybertrucks get rust spots in the rain, Deloreans don't.

@RetiredATC Not all stainless steels are created equal. There is a trade-off between resisting corrosion in various environments and other desirable traits, like the maximum sharpness that can be achieved, sharpness retention and mechanical stability. The knives getting spots may aim at a different balance. Of course, the dishwasher is a pretty aggressive environment, and quality chef knife manufacturers often recommend to hand wash. The main advantage of stainless steel is that you can let it sit whet and dirty for a while which is a no-no for regular steel knives.

Here is an article about SpaceX changing the specific stainless steel alloy during development.

Stainless steel that is washed while in contact with other alloys may rust or developed pitting due to galvanic interactions. You may want to be careful about keeping some space between the good cutlery and other kitchenware.
To remove the rust stains, if they won't easily polish off, I have become very fond of soaking in household vinegar. Iron oxide plus acetic acid yields water-soluble iron acetate, while unoxidized iron is mostly immune to the stuff

Are you sure its rust? Could it be food remnants?

When purchasing you should look for a stamp that shows the chromium to nickel content. 18/8 or 304 is best to resist rust. I use 18/0 because I'm allergic to nickel so have to deal with some rust here and there. Higher nickel content will resist rust but generally costs more. If it isn't stamped to show the nickel content then it's likely very low/zero and cheap SS.
